# How can I get the address of my program from inside the program in anchor?

Tags: anchor

Question title says it all - I know in anchor programs start with

```
declare_id!("SOME_ADDRESS");
```

but was wondering if there was something like `self.address` that would avoid me having to manually manage this address if I need it inside of an instruction somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program id is part of the `Context` provided to an instruction, so you can access it directly through there, ie:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS");

#[program]
mod basic_0 {
    use super::*;
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        let program_id = ctx.program_id;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize {}
```

See https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/0f6090950a4e65de581320d22b009b5001441e00/lang/src/context.rs#L26 for the source code